# chrome webdriver console text message is trimmed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

One of web application I'm try to test using chromedriver keeps posting some logging to browser js console and this is the only info I can send to developers once I found some complex defect. Usually driver log has entries like

```
[1.234][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Console.messageAdded {
    ...
    "text": "This is a logging line from js",
    ...
}
```

and I was happy about it until now: JS begin to dump some objects in json format, which made log line extremely long. The problem is that chrome (webdriver?) trim such lines in log file and I can't get any useful info. I can't affect log contents anyhow, json will be posted there anyway. I'm aware of logging capabilities via library interface, but effort is too big to implement/write own logs in existing testing environment.

```
capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
...
messages = driver.get_log('browser')
```

So, the question is:

Is this trim done by chrome driver? or chrome?
Are there any options or arguments which allow to get full messages in chromedriver log?